# ZF2 + DoctrineModule: Allow Doctrine Form Element ObjectSelect to be empty

Tags: php, forms, validation, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a `Zend\Form\Form` for one of my entities that uses the `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect` element to enable the user to select a referenced entity.

```
class MyEntityForm extends Zend\Form\Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // ...
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'referenced_entity',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $object_manager,
                'target_class' => 'MyOtherEntity',
                'property' => 'id',
                'display_empty_item' => true
            ],
        ]);
        // ...
    }
 }
```

The referenced entity may be empty (= the foreign key field in the database can be `NULL`). I just can't get the form to validate if no referenced entity has been selected. I would like my form to validate even if the given `referenced_entity` is empty (`null` or `""`) or not present at all (key `referenced_entity` missing from the data array).

I tried a variety of different input filter specifications, the last setup looked as follows

```
class MyEntityForm
    extends Zend\Form\Form
    implements Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface
{
    // ...
    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        return [
            // ...
            'referenced_entity' => [
                'required' => false,
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'continue_if_empty' => false
            ],
            // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

But to no avail, the validation error stays the same (excerpt of var_dump of `$form->getMessages()` after `$form->isValid()`)

```
'referenced_entity' => 
    array (size=1)
      'isEmpty' => string 'Value is required and can't be empty' (length=36)
```

Do I have to extend the `ObjectSelect` form element to change its input filter specification and remove the `isEmpty` validator or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the 'allow_empty' and 'continue_if_empty' options from your inputSpecification as they might not be necessary.

Comment: what version of zend-form are you using?

Comment: @Kwido yes, I tried a variety of combinations, none of them worked

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes composer.lock says version 2.4.10 of zendframework (yes, we have not yet changed from using the whole package to only our required components, will be done in the near future...)

Comment: Have you tried: `required => false`, `allow_empty => true`, `continue_if_empty => true`. The last being different from in your question. Have you also made sure that the Entity that your saving this too has `referenced_entity` property annotation of: 
     `* @ORM\Column(name="referenced_entity", nullable=true)` (the nullable part)

Comment: @Nukeface I did not specify the "nullable" property on the `@ORM\JoinColumn`, but doing so didn't change anything. The docs state the default value for the nullable property is `true` anyway: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn I also tried your combination of properties for the InputSpecification but to no avail either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember well, if you want to provide input filter configuration into your **`Form`** class, then you must implement the **Input*Filter*ProviderInterface** interface.
If you want to configure it at the element level then your **`Element`** class must implement the **InputProviderInterface** interface

So it would mean that your form class has to be like that:

```
class MyEntityForm
    extends Zend\Form\Form
    implements
        // this... 
        // Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface
        // must be this!
        Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    // ...
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            // ...
            'referenced_entity' => [
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => [],
                'filters' => [],
            ],
            // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already extended my `MyEntityForm` to include an `InputFilterSpecification` (see the last listing in my original message). That did not work. I tried to add the `'validators => [], 'filters' => []` part from your example, hoping that would overwrite any filters or validators that are set by the `ObjectSelect` element class, but I am still getting the same error...

Comment: You must implemtent the InputFilterProviderInterface, not the InputProviderInterface. These are two different interfaces. One is used in the elements classes and the other in the form / fieldset classes.

Comment: Sorry I sent the form too fast. Check the zf doc here : https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html in the "Hinting to the input filter" chapter. So please try to make your form class implements InputFilterProviderInterface (with the method getInputFilterSpecification() method) cause in your code you implement InputFilterSpecification

Comment: Heureka, this did it! I've never thought of the inheritance to be wrong. Such a subtle difference in the interface names, that would have never caught my attention! I've always had a weird feeling about the naming of those interfaces, and this issue just reinforces that feeling...

Comment: Important to note is that this does not only apply to `Form`s but also to `Fieldset`s!

Comment: I'm happy that it could help. Yes in fact, the Form class extends the Fieldset class in ZF2. So the way is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

`DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect` inherits `Zend\Form\Element\Select` and it includes automaticatilly [a input especification with a validator](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/release-2.4.1/src/Element/Select.php#L313) for itself.

I didn't test myself, but an way to solve this is remove this validator by adding `'disable_inarray_validator'` key in options:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // ...
    $this->add([
        'name' => 'referenced_entity',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'options' => [
            'object_manager' => $object_manager,
            'target_class' => 'MyOtherEntity',
            'property' => 'id',
            'display_empty_item' => true,
            'disable_inarray_validator' => true
        ],
    ]);
    // ...
    //or via method
    $this->get('referenced_entity')->setDisableInArrayValidator(true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do it either. The "isEmpty" validator is still being executed. The `Select` element does not offer the same functionality to disable the isEmpty validator as it does with the inArray validator. I guess I just have to extend the `ObjectSelect` element to change the validators.